# How to stop meteor.js app refreshing constantly

Tags: meteor

My relatively simple meteor app has got into the state where it refreshes constantly on load.  This means you can't use the app at all.  I have tried the following:

- meteor reset
- meteor update
- reinstall meteor
- restart computer
- reverting to old versions of my code that are known to be good

In all cases, navigating to localhost:3000 will show the page and then immediately start a page refresh loop.

Since even very old versions show this behaviour, I am guessing it is something about meteor, not about my code but I have no idea where to start looking.

So my question is, what things might cause a meteor (1.4.1.2 and 1.4.1.3 both tried) app to get into a constant page-refresh loop?

Comment: It happened to me once, but it was related to a non-standard configuration I was using, that caused the app to think it needs to be updated and refresh itself, because the autoupdate url was different from the DDP url, so the served version was always different from the one received from the autoupdate query. I don't know if this is your case, but it might be worth checking if this is what triggers the reload.

Comment: Have you tried breaking into the debugger to see what's causing the loop? I've had to do that a couple times for obscure problems that I couldn't figure out otherwise.